# Calculate Total salary

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a problem which i'm trying to solve.

In a company an emplopyee is paid as under:
If his basic salary is less than Rs. 1500, then HRA = 10% of base salary and DA = 90% of basic salary. 
If his salary is either equal to or above Rs. 1500, then HRA = Rs. 500 and DA = 98% of basic salary. If the Employee's salary is input, write a program to find his gross salary.

**Input**

3

1203

10042

1312

**Expected Output**

2406

20383.2

2624

**Actual Output**

1.5668931843000004E8

19579.800000000003

2.0325629952E8

Java Code...

```
class salary {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        int testNum;
        int[] testCases;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        testNum = in .nextInt();

        testCases = new int[testNum];

        int i = 0;

        while ( in .hasNextInt()) {
            testCases[i] = in .nextInt();
            //System.out.println(testCases[i]);
            salary(testCases[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static double salary(double n) {
        double tsal = 1; // this  will be the result
        double hra;
        double da;
        if (n < 1500) {
            hra = 0.1 * n;
            da = 0.9 * n;
            tsal = n + hra + da;
        }
        if (n >= 1500) {
            hra = 500;
            da = 0.9 * n;
            tsal = n + hra + da;
        }

        System.out.println(Math.round(tsal));
        return tsal;
    }

}
```

I can't understand where I"m going wrong. The compiler is not showing any error.

**EDIT 1:**

I changed the line "tsal = n * hra * da" to "tsal = n + hra + da" in the first if statement and changed the system.output line to

```
 "System.out.println(Math.round(tsal));"
```

still i'm not getting the desired output. Any idea how to get double value rounded off to 1 decimal place??

Comment: `tsal = n * hra * da` that's `n * n * n * 0.9 * 0.1`, or `n * n * n * 0.09`. probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line: `tsal = n * hra * da;` to `tsal = n + hra + da;`

That will help for < 1500

Also, for your RS > 1500, if DA = 98% then your code `da  = 0.9 * n;` should be `da  = 0.98 * n;`